# How to bind mount a directory in .bashrc without sudo privilege

Tags: sudo, startup, fstab, automounting, bind-mount

> NOTE: I'm working in WSL2, but my issues lies entirely within the Linux side of things. Please let me know if this is not the right place for this.

I am needing to `mount --bind` a directory whenever .bashrc is sourced - using the following:

```
if ! mountpoint -q -- "/mnt/wsl/$WSL_DISTRO_NAME"; then
    mount --bind --make-private / "/mnt/wsl/$WSL_DISTRO_NAME"
fi
```

I am getting an [expected] error: `only root can use "--bind" option`.

I have tried elevating my user privelege via `/etc/sudoers`:

```
[myusername] ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /bin/mount
```

I have also tried adding the following to `/etc/fstab`:

```
/       /mnt/wsl/Ubuntu-18.04   none    bind,user       0 0
```

Yet nothing seems to work. I would like to accomplish this as responsibly as possible without giving my user permanent admin/root privilege... or any other similarly "lazy-ish" option.

Comment: Clarify what you mean by "startup"? `.bashrc` is only read (and executed) by bash in certain situations, such as during a user terminal login. If you meant system startup, `.bashrc` is the wrong place for it.

Comment: Apologies - startup === any time the `.bashrc` is sourced. Being that it's WSL there is not an analog for system startup afaik.

Comment: Edit your original question with that clarification, so others wanting to help you can see it quickly. `.bashrc` does **not** get sourced unless you actually log in. Being WSL is not material: WSL creates a virtual machine that you can install the Linux/Unix distro of your choice, which still undergoes a full system boot process.

Answer (score 1):

You can prefix any command requiring root privileges with

```bash
wsl.exe -u root <command>
```

Or if you need to wrap the command in quotes:

```bash
wsl.exe -u root /bin/sh -c "<command>" \
  && <another command>
```

This will start a separate WSL process and run your command as root. You can either put the command all on one line, run multiple commands with the prefix, or put the script into a separate file.

Note that if you are running as root in this way, obviously `~` will resolve to the home directory of the `root` user. If you need to access the home directory of the user running this command, save it to a variable first.

#### Example

```bash
wsl.exe -u root service docker status >/dev/null || wsl.exe -u root service docker start >/dev/null
```

Note that the above command isn't the best way to start the service, as you can add a `[boot]` entry in `wsl.config` instead. So you might also be able to do that for your command.

#### Alternative

**/etc/wsl.conf**

```bash
[boot]
systemd = true
```

**/etc/wsl.config**

```bash
[boot]
command="service docker start"
```

#### Caveats

Putting such a usage of `wsl.exe -u root` in a .bashrc file will break when opening a terminal in WSL-connected Visual Studio Code. VSCode has a protection against using this privilege escalation.